# Detect speed of moving object with Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I wrote a code that marks moving objects on the video with rectangle. This is the video that I have used:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PTy2vx8Ejas&t=47s&ab_channel=macman400

The code works very good:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import copy

# upload video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test_video.mp4')

#reading two frames
ret, frame1 = cap.read()
ret, frame2 = cap.read()

while cap.isOpened():

     # get diference between two frames
     diff = cv2.absdiff(frame1, frame2)

     # convert diference in gray
     gray = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)    

     # treshold
     _, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

     dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations = 5)

     # define contours
     contours, _ = cv2.findContours(dilated, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
         
     for contour in contours:
          cnt_area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
 
          if cnt_area < 1000 or cnt_area > 4000:
               continue
          (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
          cv2.rectangle(frame1, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255))
          print(cnt_area)
          
     #cv2.drawContours(frame1, contours, -1, (0,0,255), 1)

     # show frames
     cv2.imshow('frame', frame1)
     frame1 = frame2
     ret, frame2 = cap.read()

     if cv2.waitKey(60) == 60:
          break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

Is it possible to get the speed of each rectangle?
Basically, I want to detect only fast / rapid / sudden movements. So I want to set some kind of threshold for speed of each object/rectangle.
By speed I do not mean strictly m/s or km/h, I mean some other metric that can be interpreted as speed. I want to detect only rapid movements, in this case, only persons that are in the fight.

Comment: Could you please share your video?

Comment: This is the video that I have used: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PTy2vx8Ejas&t=47s&ab_channel=macman400

Comment: thanks, this video is very brutal, though... I will look into your code as soon as I have time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you can also check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66995010/apply-heatmap-on-video-with-opencv-and-python

Comment: @Prefect Have you checked it?

Comment: Sorry, not much time for a complex question, hope you get an answer from someone else.

Comment: did you manage to calculate the speed?

Comment: Unfortunately, no